# trigger to update a record in table (table B) after insert on another table (Table A)

Tags: sql, sql-server

The catch is when a record is inserted in `table A` through the connected app, a record is inserted in `table B` as well. I need to update one of the columns on this record in table B.

If I create a trigger to insert record in table B after insert in A, app throws a primary key violation exception (rightly so).

If the trigger tries to update the record in table B, it does not happen.

Here is my code where I am trying to update table B:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TriggerName] 
ON [dbo].[fields] -- Table A
FOR INSERT NOT FOR REPLICATION 

AS

BEGIN
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    RETURN;

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF EXISTS ( ---This is to check if I need to update the B table or not
        SELECT *
        FROM roles r
        WHERE r.sys_id = (
                SELECT sys_id
                FROM inserted i
                )
            AND r.rolename = 'DTNSystemUser'
        )
BEGIN

    DECLARE @sys_id INT
    DECLARE @field_id INT
    DECLARE @role_id INT

    SELECT @sys_id = sys_id
    FROM inserted

    SELECT @field_id = field_id
    FROM inserted

    SELECT @role_id = role_id
    FROM roles
    WHERE sys_id = @sys_id
        AND rolename = 'DTNSystemUser'

        BEGIN
                UPDATE roles_permissions --Table B
                SET gpermissions=15
                WHERE sys_id=@sys_id and role_id=@role_id


        END

END
    ELSE

        BEGIN
            RETURN
        END
END


GO
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger that inserts data into new table when another table is updated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112454/trigger-that-inserts-data-into-new-table-when-another-table-is-updated)

Comment: @SabyasachiMishra  I am not trying to insert record in a table (table b) based on updates on another table (table A). That is already happening though application code. I am trying to update a column in this B table record.